# Changing case of input text (xtype: "textfield")

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

I have an input box which asks users to input a UK postcode but which specifies that this must be in lower case, for example so16 0as.  Some users find this frustrating as they would just like to copy and paste a post code into the textfield; the copied postcode may contain upper case letters ie SO16 0AS.  This will return an error.

The input code is as follows:

```
items: [{
            xtype: "textfield",
            width: 220,
            name: "search_lc",
            value: "",
            emptyText:'Enter Postcode (e.g. so16 0as)',
            fieldLabel: "Find",
            allowblank: false
        }],
```

I have tried to use **fieldStyle: 'text-transform:lowercase'** both below the fieldLabel and above it but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom validation function, see the API of Ext (GeoExt base for non-Geo stuff) for that: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validator .

Even better: use a Regular Expression, as

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    allowBlank: false,  // requires a non-empty value
    regex: /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
}
```

I am unfamiliar with the exact Regex needed for validating a UK postcode, so i allow all letters and numbers. Google tells me it is a bit more complex, see for example regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=260 .